# How to return object after completeon of .map function in a function of type promise in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using nodejs for server side code. I am using .map() inside a method of type Promise. Here the loop execution executes perfectly,but the problem is that, method returns a value before the .map() function is fully executed.

Below is the code,where in i am using ,map() function. Here i want to return created_ids array only after the .map() is completely executed,but what's happening is created_ids will be returned before insert query is called.

```
public createDomainUser(user:any):Promise<any> {
   let created_ids:any = []; 
   var md5 = require('md5');
   (user['password']) = md5(user['password']);
   return Promise.all(user.Boards.map(boardobj => {
   BasePgRepo.db.query(USER_QUERIES['insert'],vals).then(rows => { 
   created_ids.push(rows);
   })
 return created_ids;
}))
}
```

"return created_ids" should be called after the completion of map(). Am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Just return the Promise itself. `return Promise.all(user.Boards.map(boardobj => (
    BasePgRepo.db.query(USER_QUERIES['insert'], vals)
  )))` otherwise, `return created_ids` is returning a plain array, a non-Promise, that holds no meaning for `Promise.all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried to clean your code. Your mistake was missing `return` before `BasePgRepo` call.

```
import md5 from "md5";

class MyClass {
  async createDomainUser(user: any): Promise<any> {
    let created_ids: any = [];
    user['password'] = md5(user['password']);
    await Promise.all(user.Boards.map((boardobj: any) =>
      BasePgRepo.db.query(USER_QUERIES['insert'], vals)
        .then((rows: any) => {
          created_ids.push(rows);
        })));
    return created_ids;
  }
}
```